# Build json from array dynamically to use in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to build a flat Json (not sure to call it Json object or Json string), to build a tree Json hierarchy model.

```
    var data = new Array();
    data.push({"name":Rows[f][0],"parent":Rows[f][1]});  //here f is the index to the  array
```

When I give the above 'data' (flat json) to the following code to build tree json, it builds nothing - treeData.length is zero.

```
    var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
                    map[node.name] = node;
                    return map;
        }, {});

    var treeData = [];
    data.forEach(function(node) {
    var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
        if (parent) {
            (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
            .push(node);
        } else {
            treeData.push(node);
        }
    }); 
    alert(treeData.length); //Returns 0.
```

Even the following code gives the same result when input to treeData json generator.

```
    var data = new Array(); 
    for (var f=0; f<Rows.length; f++ )  {
            var tmp1={};
            tmp1[name] = Rows[f][0];
            tmp1[parent] = Rows[f][1];
            data.push(tmp1);
            }
```

But hard coding like this works.

```
    data.push({"name":"Apple","parent":"fruit"});
```

Please help to build the flat json correctly.

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/7eew5/2/)

(In the for loop method, you should write `tmp1["name"]` and `tmp1["parent"]`)

Comment: Finally this worked. adding .text to the array elements.

Thanks anyways to @tewathia.